# Installed Python, but cannot run `pip`

Tags: windows-10, python, pip, python3

I installed Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10. 
From the command line, if I enter `pip` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

It looks like something is missing (`pip` should be included by default).

The file I installed Python from is: python-3.7.3-amd64.exe (25 MB)

I tried to modify the installation, adding `pip` as an optional feature, without any improvement.

I tried to repair the previous installation, successfully, again without any improvement.

How can I fix this issue?

---

From the Windows command prompt, however, `pip` works:

`python -m pip install scipy`

Is `pip` intended to be used out of Python only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are entering `pip` in the wrong command line.

You are entering it in the Python CLI whereas it has to be used in the regular Windows command line.

> Is pip intended to be used out of Python only?

**Yes**, it is.

---

In `cmd` you can use `pip -V` to see if it is really installed properly. You can then proceed by using the following command to check what you can do:

```
pip help
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac and Linux, you can use the below command to check if pip is installed.

`python3 -m pip --version`

If pip is still not working, try to upgrade pip to the latest version:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172050)